# "White screen of death" on trying to open Flag edit form and Pathauto pattern page, error log points to includes directory

Tags: 7, migrations

Ever since migrating the site, I have been unable to open the Flag edit form from the Flag module UI, as well as the "Patterns" page in the Pathauto interface. I checked the error log in my home folder on the server and these are the errors I see:

```
    [Mon Feb 24 16:57:56 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /home/mysite/public_html/includes/database/database.inc(2168): PDOStatement->execute(Array), referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
    [Mon Feb 24 16:57:56 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /home/mysite/public_html/includes/database/database.inc(680): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array), referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
    [Mon Feb 24 16:57:56 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 /home/mysite/public_html/includes/database/database.inc(2347): DatabaseConnection->query('SELECT expire, ...', Array, Array), referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
    [Mon Feb 24 16:57:56 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr: #3 /home/mysite/public_html/includes/lock.inc(167): db_query('SELECT expire, ...', Array), referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
    [Mon Feb 24 16:57:56 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr: #4 /home/mysite/public_html/includes/lock.inc(146): lock_may_be_available('theme_registry:...'), referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
    [Mon Feb 24 16:57:56 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr: #5 /home/mysite/public_html/includes/theme.inc(449): lock_acquire('theme_registry:...'), referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
    [Mon Feb 24 16:57:56 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr: #6 /home/mysite/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc(446): ThemeRegistry->set(Array), referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
    [Mon Feb 24 16:57:56 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr: #7 [internal function]: DrupalCacheArray->__destruct(), referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
    [Mon Feb 24 16:57:56 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr: #8 {main}, referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
    [Mon Feb 24 16:57:56 2014] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /home/mysite/public_html/includes/database/database.inc on line 2168, referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
```

PHP version - 5.3.10
Memory allocated - 256M

Comment: Are you positive it's php 5.0? If so that's likely to be the problem as D7 [requires >5.2.5](https://drupal.org/requirements)

Comment: Virtualmin says "In domain [domainname]
Your system only has PHP version 5 installed, so selecting a different version for each directory is not possible."

Comment: okay, now I figure that doesn't mean that the version is 5.0

Comment: You can get your current version from the command line with `php -i | grep "PHP Version"`, or even through Drupal at /admin/reports/status

Comment: Thanks.

PHP version  5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9. 

I will edit my original post.

Comment: Make sure you have the PDO and PDO MySQL extensions enabled as well.

Comment: After consulting a friend, this was solved by increasing max_allowed_packet to 20M. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions.